# Count unique active users per database Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

This is a multi tenant question. I want to check how many users connected per database.

This query is the closest I have come:

```
SELECT datname, count(usesysid) as users
FROM pg_stat_activity
GROUP BY 1
```

But it seems not to be correct as the postgres db has 2 users and only 1 is logged in.

Is there any other way to figure out this?

It seems that every query in PGAdmin uses another process and acts like another user. So I can count processes but not "active users":

[image]

Comment: The usesysid are the same for all postgres users. Last time I checked it was 4 postgres with usesysid 10

Comment: 10;"postgres"
10;"postgres" (the number of "postgres" differ from session to session)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly which is "Count unique active users per database Postgresql", I would query

```
SELECT datname, usename, COUNT(*)
  FROM pg_stat_activity
  GROUP BY datname, usename;
```

Comment: All users from same company share the same role (usename), so it do not tells me how many users on each company that are logged in.

Comment: So, if all users from a same company share the same `usename` so you'll need to add the dimension `usename` to the aggregation. I updated the query to reflex this. Let me know if this answer your question.

Comment: This gives the exact same result as my original query. I cannot figure out why there is 2 postgres users, because I am the only admin logged in as postgres.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the result of your query, my query and your expected result. Also, the result of `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE usename = 'postgres'` will be useful.
The question why you see 2 users `postgres` even if you're the only one who connect have many possible answers. By taking a look to the columns `application_name`, `client_addr`, `state`,.. in the result of the above query, you might find the answer.

Comment: Done. It seems that I cannot count logged in users. Only open processes.